Deploying To AWS EKS - Stream closed EOF - exec format error
I am trying to deploy my Golang microservice app to AWS EKS. My Github Actions are building the images, publishing them to ECR and then I'm trying to deploy those images to EKS. When trying to run each service it returns:
│ Stream closed EOF for default/event-service-649868f85f-hdmnx (event-service)
│ exec ./eventApp: exec format error

Chat GPT mentioned this is most likely from the containers being built in the wrong architecture (arm64) trying to run on a amd64 node, but all my containers are amd64 running on x86_64 nodes.
Here is an example Dockerfile from just one of my service. They are all exactly the same.
FROM alpine:3.18

RUN mkdir /app

COPY followApp /app

WORKDIR /app

COPY app.env .
COPY db/migration ./db/migration

EXPOSE 9091

CMD [ "/app/followApp" ]

Here is my deploy.yaml Github Actions file:
name: Deploy to staging
on:
  push:
    branches:
      # Update this to staging later
      - main

jobs:
  build:
    name: Build Image
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      matrix:
        service: [event-service, feed-service, follow-service, gateway-service, group-service, marketplace-service, messaging-service, notification-service]
    steps:
    - name: Checkout code
      uses: actions/checkout@v2

    - name: Install kubectl
      uses: azure/setup-kubectl@v3
      id: install

    - name: Configure AWS credentials
      uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v2
      with:
        aws-access-key-id: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
        aws-secret-access-key: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
        aws-region: us-east-1

    - name: Login to Amazon ECR
      id: login-ecr
      uses: aws-actions/amazon-ecr-login@v1

    - name: Load secrets and save to app.env
      run: aws secretsmanager get-secret-value --secret-id ${{ matrix.service }} --query SecretString --output text | jq -r 'to_entries|map("\(.key)=\(.value)")|.[]' > backend/${{ matrix.service }}/app.env

    - name: Build, tag, and push image to Amazon ECR
      env:
        REGISTRY: ${{ steps.login-ecr.outputs.registry }}
        REPOSITORY: expatx/${{ matrix.service }}
        IMAGE_TAG: ${{ github.sha }}
      run: |
        docker build -t $REGISTRY/$REPOSITORY:$IMAGE_TAG -t $REGISTRY/$REPOSITORY:latest -f backend/${{ matrix.service }}/${{ matrix.service }}.dockerfile backend/${{ matrix.service }}/
        docker push $REGISTRY/$REPOSITORY

  deploy:
    needs: build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Install kubectl
        uses: azure/setup-kubectl@v3

      - name: Configure AWS credentials
        uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v2
        with:
          aws-access-key-id: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
          aws-secret-access-key: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
          aws-region: us-east-1

      - name: Update Kube config  
        run: aws eks --region us-east-1 update-kubeconfig --name expatx

      - name: Deploy Image to Amazon EKS 
        run: |
          kubectl rollout restart -f backend/project/k8s/deployments.yml
          kubectl apply -f backend/project/k8s/aws-auth.yaml
          kubectl apply -f backend/project/k8s/services.yml
          kubectl apply -f backend/project/k8s/ingress-grpc.yaml
          kubectl apply -f backend/project/k8s/ingress-class.yaml


Did you inspect the built image(s) as described in this relevant SO thread?
